# Analysis of spatially correlated count data from a designed agricultural experiment

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, count-data, glmmtmb, spatial-correlation

I have carried out a designed agricultural experiments with two treatments and recorded the effect on the abundance of a pest insect. The field experiment was divided into four blocks with two plots (replications) per block, resulting in 2 x 2 x 4 = 16 plots. Pest insects were counted per plant on the same 15 plants in a row in each of the replications. The pest insects originated from one or two nearby fields and are therefore not evenly distributed. The data looks like this:

| Treatment | Block | Plant | Plot | Insects |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| A | 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| B | 4 | 15 | 16 | 1 |

Since the counts of `insect` are Poisson distributed (or negative binomial, zero-inflated, generalized poisson, zero-inflated poisson ... whatever best fits the data), I was going to use a GLM (glmmTMB in R). The latest book by Zuur and Ieno (2021) gives good guidance on choosing the best distribution, so I have no questions about this.

The treatments are what I'm interested in, so the `treatment` is an essential covariate in the model. The nested structure is accounted for by `+(1|block/plot)`. This leads to the model:

```
model <- glmmTMB(insect ~ treatment + (1 | block / plot), family = poisson, data = mydata)
```

But this still doesn't take into account the spatial correlation of the 15 adjacent plants. As suggested by A.F. Zuur et al. (2009) in 'Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R', p. 161 and following, I first made a bubble plot to get an idea of the spatial patterns. I used the standardized residuals from a simple model with no spatial/correlation structure

```
simpel_model <- glm(insect ~ treatment, family = "poisson", data = mydata)
E <- rstandard(simp_model)
```

and the coordinates of the plants. In the bubble plot you can clearly see the 16 plots with the 15 plants in a row (distance from plant 1 to plant 15 is about 5m). As the positive and negative residuals are grouped together, it looks to me like there is a high spatial correlation.

[image: Bubble plot showing the residuals of each plant in the field (by x and y coordinates), many of the high and low residuals are grouped together]

I also produced a semi-variogram to see if it would be appropriate to use one of the suggested correlation structures such as `correlation = corGaus()` in `gls` (probably I would have to use `+ gau()` in `glmmTMB` for my purpose). As my understanding is that the spatial correlation occurs mainly within the 5m plant rows, I also created a semi-variogram with `cutoff = 5`.

[image: semi-variogram with distance >30m and no clear pattern]
[image: semi-variogram with distance cutoff at 5m, also with no clear pattern]

In none of the variograms do I see any of the proposed correlation patterns (Gaussian, Exponential, Linear...). Unfortunately I have no ideas how to proceed now.

Does anyone have any idea how I can implement the correct correlation structure in my model?