# GLMM on temporally correlated count data from a designed agricultural experiment

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, count-data, time-varying-covariate, glmmtmb

I have carried out a designed agricultural experiment with two treatments and recorded the effect on the abundance of a pest insect on three dates. The field experiment was divided into four blocks with two plots (replications) per block, resulting in 2 x 2 x 4 = 16 plots. Pest insects were counted per plant on the same 15 plants in a row in each of the replications ([I wrote another post, where asking how to deal with this spatial correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/612703/analysis-of-spatially-correlated-count-data-from-a-designed-agricultural-experim)). The pest insects originated from one or two nearby fields and are therefore not evenly distributed. The data looks like this:

| Treatment | Block | Plot | Date | Plant | Insects |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 2019-06-18 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 1 | 2019-06-18 | 2 | 5 |
| A | 1 | 1 | 2019-06-18 | 3 | 2 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| B | 4 | 16 | 2019-07-10 | 15 | 1 |

I have three Date levels `"2019-06-18", "2019-06-25", "2019-07-10"`. I have already analysed the data date by date. I used the suggested error structure from Jones, Harden, Crawley (2022) "The R Book", chapter 13, for nested (hierarchical) structures:

```
single_date_model <- glmmTMB(insect ~ treatment + (1 | block/plot), family="poisson", 
              data = subset(mydata, DATE == "2019-06-25"))
```

However, I would like to analyse all dates at once. The above book suggests adding `+ (time | random)` to the model, which is in my case should be `+ (cDATE | BLOCK / PLOT)` (I changed `DATE` to `cDATE` by `mydata$cDATE <- as.integer(mydata$DATE) - 18064` to get a continuous variable starting at 1). As an alternative, they suggest adding time as a fixed effect and comparing the models. These are the models:

```
t_random_model <- glmmTMB(insect ~ treatment + (fDATE | block / plot), family = "poisson", data = mydata, control=glmmTMBControl(optimizer=optim, optArgs=list(method="BFGS")))

t_fixed_model <- glmmTMB(insect ~ treatment + cDATE + (1 | block / plot), family = "poisson", data = mydata, control=glmmTMBControl(optimizer=optim, optArgs=list(method="BFGS")))
```

(I added `control=glmmTMBControl(optimizer=optim, optArgs=list(method="BFGS"))` to both as suggested in the vignette [Troubleshooting with glmmTMB](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/troubleshooting.html) in order to avoid convergence problems.)

Compring the models with `anova()` shows, that the `t_random_model` is significantly better with a far lower AIC. However, unlike my data with three irregular time points, the example in the book has five equidistant time points, and I'm not sure that the way I did it is still valid.

I have also tried a model with an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck covariance structure from the vignette [Covariance structures with glmmTMB](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html), which is said to be able to handle irregular time points. For the model I prepared the data with `mydata$numDATE <- numFactor(mydata$cDATE)` and then ran:

```
t_corr_model <- glmmTMB(insect ~ treatment + ou(numDATE + 0 | block / plot),
                       data = mydata)
```

Comparing it with `anova()` says that it's a worse model. However, I'm not sure if one model is nested within the other and if it's valid to compare them.

Are all of these models valid ways to analyse the data? Is `anova()` the right way to find out which model is best or should I go another way?